# Unresolved error in main (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

So i keep getting this error message and i have no idea what it means or how to respond.  Heres my code.  When i go to a different compiler, i dont get this issue.  Thanks in advance!

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

public class QuestionEight {

    public QuestionEight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] newArr = new int[1000];
        for(int a = 0; a<1000; a++) {
            newArr[a] = countNumbers();
        }
        double sum = (double)sumOfArray(newArr);
        double attempts = (double)1000;
        System.out.println("The average is " + sum/attempts);
    }
    public static int countNumbers() {
        int sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        while(sum<1) {
            sum = Math.floor(10.0*Math.random());
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    public static int sumOfArray(int[]a) {
        int[] tempArr = new int[a.length];
        for(int c = 0; c<a.length; c++)
            tempArr[c] = a[c];
        for(int d = 1; d<a.length; d=d+2) {
            tempArr[d] = tempArr[d] + tempArr[d-1];
            if(d==tempArr.length-1) {
                return tempArr[d];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: is that literally all the error text that you get? Also, that's an odd way to sum an array...

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "different compiler"?

Comment: it work in BlueJ.  and yeah, thats basically all the error text i got

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, except that you might want to change

```
sum = Math.floor(10.0 * Math.random());
```

to

```
sum = (int) Math.floor(10.0 * Math.random());
```

since [`Math.floor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) returns a value of type `double`.